# Firebase set security and rules for current user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to let the authorized current user read and write to his own data to the Firebase database. My security data looks like this:

```js
{
  "features" : {
    "-KDUBJIPwvLCK-1lV4bM" : {
      "e1fd0ccb-370a-4a6f-86af-87fdf97d25a0" : "een"
    },
    "-KDUBLUr6K_PMxWkgcof" : {
      "e1fd0ccb-370a-4a6f-86af-87fdf97d25a0" : "twee"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "e1fd0ccb-370a-4a6f-86af-87fdf97d25a0" : {
      "email" : "tjalling@horecalife.nl",
      "image" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA\r\nABxpRE9UAAAA",
      "name" : "tjalling dijkstra",
      "telephone number" : "06580055"
    }
  }
}
```

`-KDUBJIPwvLCK-1lV4bM` is an autoId gotten from `childByAutoId()` method

`e1fd0ccb-370a-4a6f-86af-87fdf97d25a0` is a uid (unique user id).

`een` is the value of a certain feature.

My security rules are:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "features": {
      "$autoId" : { 
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

If I write Firebase rules like this, permission to `setValue()` is denied on the features part.

> 2016-03-22 17:51:27.077 Herodus[884:228445] [Firebase] setValue: or removeValue: at /features/-KDUEEZ4z-FCAoUci-rW failed: permission_denied.

A new feature is added with this code snippet:

```
let featureContents = addFeatureTextField.text 
if featureContents != "" { 
  let newFeature: String = featureContents! 
  let featureDict = [ uid: newFeature] 
  let ref = DataService.dataService.FEATURE_REF.childByAutoId()
  ref.setValue(featureDict)
```

Somebody, any clue what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree and security rules in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON and security rules as text. You can get the JSON easily by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON and security rules as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual data and use them in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36161137/edit) link right under your question that allows you to put it into your question.

Comment: Hope you can help me to the answer Frank, as an engineer at Firebase ;-)

Comment: OK. You've added the parts and I've edited it into something more readable.  Now can you add a code snippet of an operation that fails? Be sure to include the necessary details of what data you're writing and what location you're writing it to.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Much appreciated. At first, this is the error message: 2016-03-22 17:51:27.077 Herodus[884:228445] [Firebase] setValue: or removeValue: at /features/-KDUEEZ4z-FCAoUci-rW failed: permission_denied.  A new feature is added with this code snippet: let featureContents = addFeatureTextField.text
        
        if featureContents != ""  {
            
        let newFeature: String = featureContents!
            
            let featureDict = [ uid: newFeature]
      
            let ref = DataService.dataService.FEATURE_REF.childByAutoId()
            ref.setValue(featureDict)

Comment: Problem isn't in the used code, problem lies in the security rules, if I set them to: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}  Everything works perfectly, but if I set the rules to: {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    
     "features": {
      "$autoId" : { 
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
    
    
  }
  
  
}
} The error message occurs

Answer (score 1):

You're writing to this path:

```
/features/-KDUEEZ4z-FCAoUci-rW
```

Your rules only give write permission on this path:

```
/features/$autoId/$uid
```

You'll want to write the data using something like:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).setValue(featureDict)
```